# Scroll to index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have one table view that is filled from rss, I am trying to scroll it to position 9 when the device is in portait and position 1 when the device is in landscape but I get this error

> exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView
>   scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (1) beyond
>   bounds (0) for section (0).'

I don't know why... this is the code i am trying to use

```
NSIndexPath *scrollToPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[self.TableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollToPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error. It's telling you that you have at most one row in section `0`. Therefore you need to populate your tableView further or take a higher row, `0` for instance.

Comment: but the table view is populated I have 14 rows . and 1 section

Comment: Apparently not at the time you hit these two lines. Use `NSLog` right before this to query the number of rows in section `0`.

Comment: how do I get the number of rows ? i am using scrollToRowAtIndexPath in another function named -(void)MoveTableToRow; but I am watching that the table is full Thanks

Comment: @Alfonso When are you calling those method? At what point in the live cycle of your UITableView subclass?

Comment: I am calling the method when the device rotates after the table is loaded thanks